# Using spring-jdbc, obtain execution plan as well

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I am using spring-jdbc to perform queries, so on application level, my queries are done using Spring calls, such as

```
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate  jdbcTemplate;
...
List<DataDomain> events = jdbcTemplate.query(
            selectByStartAndEnd, // sql line
            parameters, // sql varaible parameters
            dataMapper // mapper
            );
```

I would like to add to the log the execution plan in order to see how things are performing. (While it is of course possible to get that manually for each query from a database UI client, I might want to output these for massive amount of various queries in the code in order to detect inefficient queries from the collected logs)

What would be the best way to do it on Spring-jdbc level?

Comment: Maybe by using AOP and setting an aspect around the executed DAO method would solve your scenario

Comment: I’m a beginner so could you possibly point me to some examples regarding AOP :)?